# ASP.NET: Uploading files error "The given path's format is not supported"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to save files

```
string path= "~/Pre/IntraExtra/" + Session["id"].ToString() + "_" + FileUpload1.FileName;
FileUpload11.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path));
```

but it gives this error "The given path's format is not supported."

---

It is working now .. 
I just removed the (~/) , Thank you all

Comment: No idea about either language but maybe using the absolute path would help?

Comment: Probably better to use: System.IO.Path.Combine() instead of +

Comment: thanks for replaying, I've tried both, but nothing worked

Comment: what is the absolute path of the location on the server...?

Comment: paste what you have tried using the absolute path...

Comment: What's the value of your "path" variable when you run the first line above?  You might have some invalid characters in your Session["id"], post your output.

Comment: So the tilde (~) may be. Where's the rest of it, should be some more characters to give the OS a clue on what it should expand to. No to mention I'm pretty sure you aren't limited to 8.3 in a .net method...

Comment: string path= "c:/Projects/Blog/Pre/IntraExtra/" + Session["id"].ToString() + "_" + FileUpload1.FileName;
FileUpload11.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path));

Comment: @TonyHopkinson It usually works with folder name only without any (~) or (..) ,,

Comment: @Zachary this is my output "~/Pre/IntraExtra/2_Chrysanthemum.jpg"

Comment: Shouln't you be using forward slashes \?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working now .. I just removed the (~/) , Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

for example if I had code that was set like the following on my end it works.. also notice the @ symbol I am using .. this is for a literal file path this way I don't have to use "\ in the file path.. try the following code as see if it works.. replace with your code variables.

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {

            fname = FileUpload1.FileName;
            spath = "~\Pre\IntraExtra\" + FileUpload1.FileName;
            fpath = Server.MapPath("Uploaded");
            fpath = fpath + @"\" + FileUpload1.FileName;            
            desc = TextBox2.Text;
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(fpath))
            {
                Label1.Text = "File Name already exists!";
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(fpath);
            }
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to use the Path.Combine method:

```
string path= "~/Pre/IntraExtra/" + Session["id"].ToString() + "_"; ; 
string combinedPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, FileUpload1.FileName);

FileUpload11.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(combinedPath));
```

If this does not work, then could you give us the filename and path?